# xr package not working "Incomplete \ifx"

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals

I am trying to use xr for crossreferences between two documents. I've used it before without a problem for a different project.

Here's the error message I get:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xr.sty))
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 12.
<inserted text> 
            \fi 
<*> main
```

The call to `\externaldocument` is on line 12 of the main document. I haven't been able to find any problem like this. Any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Edited:

With just these lines in the main.tex it still fails with the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{supporting}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

The supporting.aux file contains:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\zref@newlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\bibstyle{pnas-new}
\babel@aux{english}{}
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{1}{}{page.1}{}}
\xdef\lastpage@lastpage{1}
\xdef\lastpage@lastpageHy{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@section@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{section@totc}\fi\setcounter{section@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@figure@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{figure@totc}\fi\setcounter{figure@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@table@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{table@totc}\fi\setcounter{table@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@NAT@ctr@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{NAT@ctr@totc}\fi\setcounter{NAT@ctr@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@movie@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{movie@totc}\fi\setcounter{movie@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@dataset@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{dataset@totc}\fi\setcounter{dataset@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@SItext@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{SItext@totc}\fi\setcounter{SItext@totc}{0}
```

The external document is a [PNAS template from overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pnas-template-for-supplementary-information/wqfsfqwyjtsd).

Comment: impossible to guess unless you show some input, try to make a small self contained example that shows this problem (probably at most the first 12 lines of your main document, and the `.aux` file that is referenced. is needed)

Comment: I edited the post. Please let me know if there is other information that would help

Comment: Is your external document using `hyperref`? Then maybe use `\usepackage{xr-hyper}`

Comment: @samcarter xr-hyper is the same :-) (updated answer with fix coming up)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update** `xr` has been updated with this fix in version

```
[2019/01/05 v5.04 eXternal References (DPC)]
```

---

It seems I last edited the code for `xr` in 1994. It seems like only yesterday...

`xr` doesn't take kindly to `\if` tests in the `aux` file. A fix is relatively simple as shown below, I'll try to get an update into the next release.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter
\long\def\XR@test#1#2#3#4\XR@{%
  \let\XR@next\@gobbletwo
  \ifx#1\newlabel
    \let\XR@next\@firstoftwo%
  \else\ifx#1\@input
     \let\XR@next\@secondoftwo
  \fi\fi
   \XR@next{\newlabel{\XR@prefix#2}{#3}}{\edef\XR@list{\XR@list#2\relax}}%
  \ifeof\@inputcheck\expandafter\XR@aux
  \else\expandafter\XR@read\fi}
\makeatother

\externaldocument{supporting}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

Hmm actually it is enough to have

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname wibble\endcsname\relax\relax\fi
```

in the referenced aux file.

Possibly `xr` could be more defensive against weird code in the aux file, I'll look later but meanwhile you can process your document if you reference a copy of the auxfile and in the copy delete the block

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@section@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{section@totc}\fi\setcounter{section@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@figure@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{figure@totc}\fi\setcounter{figure@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@table@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{table@totc}\fi\setcounter{table@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@NAT@ctr@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{NAT@ctr@totc}\fi\setcounter{NAT@ctr@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@movie@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{movie@totc}\fi\setcounter{movie@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@dataset@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{dataset@totc}\fi\setcounter{dataset@totc}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@SItext@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{SItext@totc}\fi\setcounter{SItext@totc}{0}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Both seem to work with the full documents.

Comment: @doubledaffy888 OK thanks for the confirmation, I'll try to get an update out before the next 24 years are up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle May I urge an update in the next 24 days, please? :P

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks so much for your solution! FYI your code above "\makeatletter ... \makeatother" worked like a charm when added to my .tex files, but messing with the \expandafter section of the .aux files didn't. I am using the most recent PNAS templates in TexShop, if that matters. I thought that might be useful info for the planned update.

Comment: @AndreaKay this should not be needed now if you have an up to date system `[2019/01/05 v5.04 eXternal References (DPC)]` version of xr has this change

Comment: Just noticed that `xr-hyper` would also need a similar update?

Comment: @LianTzeLim yes I did hope to combine xr and xr-hyper but that's a bit tricky so updating xr-hyper is on my list of jobs to do....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks and no worries, the manual patch works just fine for `xr-hyper`!

Comment: @LianTzeLim if you have any test files and could check https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/commit/0e4401d4844807f52a00a974b4afd2c656c86558  I hope to push that to ctan at the weekend:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's working perfectly, many thanks!! :D